# Using the perf events from perf list programatically

Tags: linux, performance, perf, intel-pmu

When I run `perf list` on my Linux system I get a long list of available perf events.

Is it possible to list and use these events programatically from another process, using [`perf_event_open(2)`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/perf_event_open)? That is, how can I get this list from another process and determine the corresponding values to populate in `perf_event_attr`?

I'm not looking for solutions that use another third-party listing of the events, e.g,. libpfm4 or jevents. I know some events can be reconstructed from the files in `/sys/devices/cpu/events/` (and similar files for other event types), but these are a small subset of the events that `perf list` shows.

Comment: perf list has several event sets, check `perf list -h`: `hw|sw|cache|tracepoint|pmu|sdt|event_glob`. Most events are from cache and pmu sets. You can download perf sources from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/ and check function [cmd_list from builtin-list.c file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/tools/perf/builtin-list.c#L24), then print_pmu_events. Some are scanned from /sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/events, other are printed from internal lists from file `pmu-events/pmu-events.c`

Answer (score 2):

There is no solution to get full list of raw events from kernel (with any syscall like perf_event_open(2)) without using third-party (or [first party](https://download.01.org/perfmon/index/)) lists. Perf tool uses some basic events scanned from `/sys/bus/event_source/devices/cpu/events` and similar sysfs folders, but it has its own list of cpu model specific events: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/tools/perf/pmu-events, and [there is readme file](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/tools/perf/pmu-events/README) which points that perf uses [jevents](https://github.com/andikleen/pmu-tools/tree/master/jevents) (perf has 8 MB of x86 json event lists, at [tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/x86))

> The contents of this directory allow users to specify PMU events in their
> CPUs by their symbolic names rather than raw event codes (see example below).
> The main program in this directory, is the 'jevents', which is built and
> executed *BEFORE* the perf binary itself is built.
> The 'jevents' program tries to locate and process JSON files in the directory
> tree tools/perf/pmu-events/arch/foo.

You can download perf sources from https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/ and use some source code navigation tools to check cmd_list function  builtin-list.c file (with some undocumented options). Also you can build perf tools from these sources and there will be compilation of jevents (`HOSTCC   pmu-events/jevents.o`, `LINK     pmu-events/jevents`) early in perf building.

Current cpu model is detected from table  pmu_events_map (pmu-events/pmu-events.c) by perf_pmu__find_map (util/pmu.c) called from pmu_add_cpu_aliases, called from [pmu_lookup](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/tools/perf/util/pmu.c#L810), from perf_pmu__find, from perf_pmu__scan from print_pmu_events from cmd_list (handler of `perf list` builtin command).

As of [5.5 version of perf](https://mirrors.edge.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/tools/perf/v5.5.0/perf-5.5.0.tar.xz) (from linux kernel 5.5 as perf is part of linux kernel), there is no raw dump of event list with description. There is undocumented option `perf list --raw-dump` which will print list of all events for every available monitoring unit, for example, `pmu`: `perf list --raw-dump pmu |tr ' ' '\n'`. The output of this raw dump is unstable between perf versions.

Kernel part of perf_events subsystem has no full event lists in [arch/x86/events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/arch/x86/events) or [kernel/events](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.5.19/source/kernel/events) folders, only mapping of standard perf events (listed in sysfs) like cycles or cpu/branch-misses/ to raw events of specific cpu model.